# .NET Core: How to create solution folders from the command line

Tags: .net-core

I am organising a new project, and I would like to create as much of it as possible from the command line.

I like to put my test projects into a solution folder. However, the command `dotnet sln add` seems somewhat restricted. Its argument list seems to consist only of a list of project files to add.

Is there a way of specifying a solution folder (as opposed to a physical folder) when adding newly created projects (test projects in my case, but the question is more general)?

Comment: What do you mean by solution folder as opossed to a physical folder?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/03/27/using-solution-folders/

Comment: I doubt this is possible in `.net-core`. All this logical structure seems to be stored in Visual Studio's `.suo` file. What is wrong with physical folders?

Comment: It's possible using Visual Studio. I just wondered how easy or not it would be to do it with a command-line script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible, you need create the physical structure folder like the solution structure folders

```
dotnet new <typeproj> --output "physical/domain" --name "domain"

dotnet new <typeproj> --output "physical/service" --name "service"
```

after open the solution with visual studio, create the "**physical**" solution folder and add the previous projects that you already have ready

Comment: I also wonder whether it's a good idea or not. Does a logical folder that doesn't correspond to the physical file structure add much in the way of value? I decided to use physical folders rather than solution folders in the end.

Answer (score 11):

From this [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln#examples)

```
dotnet sln yoursolution.sln add pathofyourproject\yourprojectfile.csproj --solution-folder solutionfoldername
```

If the solution folder doesn't exist, this command create a new solution folder. In the other cases, this command add a project to your solution folder.

Answer (score 8):

I just accomplished this using .Net Core 2.2 by adding a new project to `Tests\UnitTests\UnitTests.csproj` folder first, then running the `dotnet sln add` from the solution root.

**Initial Folder Structure**

[image: Initial Folder Structure]

**Adding `UnitTest.csproj` inside `Tests\UnitTests`**

*Ran from folder containing `TestMvcCore2.sln`*

```
dotnet new classlib -o .\Tests\UnitTests -n UnitTests
```

**Adding `UnitTest.csproj` to `TestMvcCore2.sln`**

*Ran from folder containing `TestMvcCore2.sln`*

```
dotnet sln add .\TestMvcCore2.sln  .\Tests\UnitTests\UnitTests.csproj
```

**Creates a `Tests` solution file in the visual studio sln**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore21), if you want to create new solution, you have to write `dotnet new sln`. This command will create a solution file in current directory named with the name of current directory. Also, you can specify the name of output solution file by `dotnet new sln -o <SOLUTION_NAME>`. **This will also create a folder with the name you specify.** To add projects to this solution enter in command prompt: `dotnet sln <YOUR_SOLUTION_NAME> add <PROJECT_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD> <PROJECT_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD> <PROJECT_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD> ...` **This will add all the projects you've specified with its folders to the solution you've specified.**

Comment: Thanks for the good info! FYI I don't think this is what the OP was asking. I think he's asking about a folder inside the Visual Studio IDE that can hold multiple projects.